# Optimize the video upload time (Cloudinary)

Tags: php, jquery, video, file-upload

I have a problem regrading upload video to cloudinary. I am using the PHP framework of cloudinary for uploading the video.But the problem occurs when I upload a video upto 5MB or grater , then firstly it will upload to my server and then upload to the cloudinary server.

As you all know the values in $_FIELS array are coming after the file is uploaded to the server, So my question is , How i can skip this step (Upload video to my server first) or any other way I can reduce the time of uploading in PHP framework of cloudinary.

Thanks in advance.